# T1 space in general topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be the topological space where $τ = \{A \subseteq X : p \in A\} \cup \{\varnothing\}$ (i.e., $\tau$ is the $p$-inclusion topology). Then show that $(X,\tau)$ is not a $T_1$-space.

I know that the definition

> A space $X$ is called a $T_1$-space if for every $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$ there exists two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x \in U$, $y \notin U$ and $y \in V$, $x \notin V$.

So $p$ in $A$ and $A$ in $X$.

Comment: How can you separate $p$ from $x \neq p$?

Comment: Also, it is `\in` and `\notin` to get $\in$ and $\notin$.

Comment: $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ **is** a $T_1$ space if $|X|=1$, so you need to assume that $X$ has more than one point.

Comment: Im edit with ∈ and ∉.i havent this in my phon .

Comment: How can i assume the two points

Comment: @eslamababneh What Brian is trying to say is that the result is not true as written. You have to add the hypothesis $|X| \geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The singleton $\{p\}$ is not closed, as $X\setminus \{p\}$ is not open: it does not contain $p$, nor is it empty (if $|X| \ge 2$, which is necessary anyway, so the original exercise was incomplete too).

If you're unfamiliar with the fact $X$ is $T_1$ iff for all $x \in X$, $\{x\}$ is closed, which I used above, you can pick $q \neq p$ by the assumption $|X| \ge 2$ again and note that there is *no* open set $U$ that contains $q$ but **not** $p$: the only open set that does not contain $p$ is $\emptyset$ and that is ruled out by $q \in U$..

Comment: Thank you, Professor Henno
So I found the question in the notebook and it seems incomplete as you all said and I apologize for that.
Do you have an email to contact you? I have some questions in this area

Comment: @eslamababneh Not a professor, I'm afraid. Just post questions on this site, and I'll see if I have time to answer them..

Comment: God willing, you will become a professor.
As this site you cannot ask for it daily after 3 days is allowed.